# Cannot convert String to Integer in Java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have written a function to convert string to integer

```
   if ( data != null )
   {
        int theValue = Integer.parseInt( data.trim(), 16 );
        return theValue;
   }
   else
       return null;
```

I have a string which is 6042076399 and it gave me errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6042076399"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
```

Is this not the correct way to convert string to integer?

Comment: Note that by specifying 16 as the second parameter to `parseInt`, you are parsing the string as a hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the way I prefer to do it:

Edit (08/04/2015):

As noted in the comment below, this is actually better done like this:

```
String numStr = "123";
int num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
```

Comment: Unless things have changed, `Integer.parseInt()` is the preferred method as it will cache commonly used values to improve performance. Creating a new Integer will always create a new Integer object. However, this was pre-Java 5 - I wouldn't be surprised if both do the same thing now.

Answer (score 9):

An `Integer` can't hold that value. 6042076399 (413424640921 in decimal) is greater than 2147483647, the maximum an integer can hold.

Try using `Long.parseLong`.

Comment: He's using primitive types. I would recommend a `long` before a `Long`. I would also possibly even recommend a `BigInteger` before a `Long`, although I'm not entirely sure about that.

Answer (score 4):

That's the correct method, but your value is larger than the maximum size of an `int`.

The maximum size an `int` can hold is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, or 2,147,483,647. Your value is 6,042,076,399. You should look at storing it as a `long` if you want a primitive type. The maximum value of a long is significantly larger - 2<sup>63</sup> - 1. Another option might be [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 2):

That string is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE.  You can't parse something that is out of range of integers. (they go up to 2^31-1, I believe).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the others answered, if you have a string of more than 8 hexadecimal digits (but up to 16 hexadecimal digits), you could convert it to a long using `Long.parseLong()` instead of to an int using `Integer.parseInt()`.