# How to determine whether a string contains an integer?

Tags: java

Say you have a string that you want to test to make sure that it contains an integer before you proceed with other the rest of the code. What would you use, in java, to find out whether or not it is an integer?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to check whether it contains an integer or with it is an integer? abc123 or 123456?

Comment: @Ash **to find out whether or not it is an integer** - to me, the question is clear (the title is ambigious).

Comment: You may also want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517686/cannot-convert-string-to-integer-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to make sure that it is *only* an integer and convert it to one, I would use [parseInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) in a `try/catch`. However, if you want to check if the string contains a number then you would be better to use the [String.matches](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) with [Regular Expressions](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html): `stringVariable.matches("\\d")`

Answer (score 8):

You can check whether the following is true:    `"yourStringHere".matches("\\d+")`

Comment: As a clarification, this checks if your string matches the regular expression "\\d+" which is one or more digits [0-9].

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = "abc123";
for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: try "for(char c : s.toCharArray())" instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache [StringUtils.isNumeric](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric(java.lang.CharSequence)) .

Answer (score 1):

I use the method matches() from the String class:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)
    String lectura;
    int number;
    lectura = input.next();
    if(lectura.matches("[0-3]")){
         number = lectura;
    }
```

This way you can also validate that the range of the numbers is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. User regular expression:

   `Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\d+\\s*$").matcher(myString).find();`
2. Just wrap Integer.parse() by try/catch(NumberFormatException)

Comment: Will the regex recognize `١` as a digit?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know this character. What is this?

Comment: It is ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE. Try for yourself: `System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("١"));`

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look at [java.util.Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Example:

```
new Scanner("456").nextInt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use Googles Guava

```
String text = "13567";
CharMatcher charMatcher = CharMatcher.DIGIT;
int output = charMatcher.countIn(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
public static boolean isInteger(String p_str)
{
    if (p_str == null)
        return false;
    else
        return p_str.matches("^\\d*$");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the method Integer.parseInt() at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: When linking to a version of the API, I would suggesting using a more up to date version.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("8.0")` throws an exception, despite 8.0 can fit into an int without loss

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to test, if a String contains an integer value only, write a method like this:

```
public boolean isInteger(String s) {
  boolean result = false;
  try {
    Integer.parseInt("-1234");
    result = true;
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // no need to handle the exception
  }
  return result;
}
```

`parseInt` will return the `int` value (-1234 in this example) or throw an exception.

Comment: `NumberFormatException`is a `RuntimeExcption`. Will catching a RuntimeException not be dangerous or "evil", for example when used in transactions, which maybe marked as rollback because a RuntimeException was thrown?

Answer (score -1):

```
int number = 0;
try { 
   number = Integer.parseInt(string); 
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is old and was already answered. Typically, it is best not to resurrect stale threads unless your response contributes something significantly new or different over previous answers.