# Scan a String for certain content

Tags: java, string, character

I want to scan a String and its content. I want to return an error message if there are any character in the string. For example: int a = myFunction("123"); will save "123" in a, but when the user tries to do something like int a = myFunction("12s32"); it should return the error, because there is a character in the string. This is what i got so far:

```
public class Parseint {
    public static int parseInt(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Der String enthaelt keine Zeichen");
            return -1;
        } else {
            int sum = 0;
            int position = 1;
            for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                int number = str.charAt(i) - '0';
                sum += number * position;
                position = position * 10;
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = parseInt("");
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to exclude letters - you may want to exclude non-digits. (You may want to use a tag or otherwise mention a specific programming language.) You know how to use a conditional statement: `if (<invalid>) { <complain>
            return <exceptional value>;` (no need to use an `else` after this (early out): decreases nesting depth/indentation). You know how to denote a `char` literal and perform arithmetic with it: `str.charAt(i) - '0'`. You can do comparisons, too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My way of thinking is to create a for-loop which searchs for "invalid" input. In my case everything except numbers. So im stuck in this situation and I dont know how to implement this. Should I do a comparison for every banned letter? Or should I only execute my function when the argument contains only numbers and nothing else?

Comment: You should _document, in the code, what it is supposed to accomplish_. You should assume that most time is spent on valid input: just try to proceed with useful processing and when you can't, give a meaningful indication of _why_.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a try and catch like in this link suggests would work perfectly

[A simple try and catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388546/how-to-find-of-if-a-string-contains-and-integer-or-not#4388610)