# what should I do, If I want to insert integer data in ms access?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
Connection conn;
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD SHAHAB\\STUD1.accdb");
String username = tf.getText();
String password = String.valueOf(pf.getPassword());
PreparedStatement pst;
pst = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SUN (Username,Password)" + "values(?,?)");

pst.setString(1, username);
pst.setString(2, password);
```

I just want to enter integer data in database instead of string.How should i replace string with int in this code? Which method should i use for getting integer data from `TextField`.

Comment: It takes very little effort on your own to find the solution yourself. Go to [the javadoc for PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and find the correct one of the `set<TypeName>` methods.

Comment: would you please show me the format how do i get integer data from textfield@fabian

Comment: consider asking "which method should i use for getting integer data from textfield" in a separate question, and post the appropriate code for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java

Comment: I am trying to do this but i didn't{ int username=tf.getInt();
             String password=String.valueOf(pf.getPassword());
             PreparedStatement pst;
                 pst=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SUN (Username,Password)"+"values(?,?)");
                
                 pst.setInt(1, username);
                 pst.setString(2,password);
                }

Comment: getText() from textbox then convert string to integer then insert...

Comment: can you plz show me how should i convert string to integer if you don't mind because i am new in java plzzz @Maharaj

Comment: @Shahabkhan ``Integer.valueOf(tf.getText());``. If this question is really about that conversion and not about access/preparedstatement, it's quality is even worse than what everyone thought.

Comment: Query will be like "insert into table_name values ("+ Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText()) +")"

Comment: you are not understanding me. I am just going to post the complete code ,so that you can better understand my problem@f1sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Added conversion from string to int.

Use:

```
    //if the data is an integer represented as String 
    String intAsString = "5";
    //convert it. catch NumberFormatException exceptions 
    int intValue = Integer.parseInt(intAsString);
    //update 
    pst.setInt(3, intValue);
```

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int,%20int)).

Comment: No you are not understanding what i am trying to say....You are just showing me a method for setting int data in a textfield.But how should i get integer data.for example if i want to get string data then i will do this 'String  u=tf.getText' but what should i do for getting integer data?

Comment: So you are asking how to convert a ``String`` into an ``Integer``?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517686/cannot-convert-string-to-integer-in-java